# IBM Worklight - How do I patch Cordova?

Tags: mobile, cordova, windows-8, ibm-mobilefirst

While adding support for the Windows 8 environment, I've hit a Cordova bug. The folders are being reported as files when I get the directory listing: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-5774

I want to apply the patch in my project as I understand you cannot upgrade the Cordova version in a Worklight project.

I am using Worklight 6.1.0.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out a way to patch (JavaScript patch).. I am sure this is not a permnant solution - but a adhoc one till the patched Cordova is available with a new version of Worklight.

In my case the bug was in `FileProxy.js`. I created a directory structure to mirror the location of the problem file and added the patched file there.(`www\worklight\plugins\org.apache.cordova.file\src\windows8\FileProxy.js`).

At build time the cordova files are copied first and then `www` contents are copied after... so my patched file overwrote the one with the bug.

I'm sure this is not a supported way by Worklight - but I am no longer blocked.

Comment: Indeed. A patched Cordova will be provided in the near future.

Answer (score 1):

It is currently not possible to *replace or patch* the Cordova version that is being used in Worklight. In Worklight v6.1.0, Cordova v3.1 is used.

If you are an IBM customer or business partner you can open a PMR to see if an iFix can be produced that will contain a patched version of Cordova 3.1.

Comment: I need to either be able to patch a file or upgrade to cordova 3.4.0