# cordova 3.7 in worklight 6.3

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, cordova-3

Our product is using Worklight 6.3 (which contains Cordova 3.6.3).  There is apparently a bug introduced in Cordova 3.6 that doesn't allow selenium tests to be run against it.  Is there a supported way we can substitute the latest version of Cordova in Worklight 6.3?

Please see the post below for the problems we're facing:
https://github.com/selendroid/selendroid/issues/658

related link:
https://github.com/selendroid/selendroid/pull/788

Comment: As idan said there isn't any automated way to do it instead try to update the cordova.js and cordova.jar file manually before creating the .apk file (Note: The auto-generated android project will replace the files every-time when you Build your Worklight Project)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way for you, as a developer using MobileFirst Platform 6.3, to replace the bundled Cordova as it will be regenerated during each build in MFP Studio.

What we can do is patch the Cordova build that is used in MFP with the fix you've linked to. What you need to do is to open a support ticket (PMR), requesting this.

Link to this question in the PMR.

Answer (score 0):

@tedL I'v had to deal with Cordova bugs specific to Windows in the past. See my answer in [IBM Worklight - How do I patch Cordova?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21907440/ibm-worklight-how-do-i-patch-cordova/22007677#22007677) on how I was able to add the patched files in to a automated Worklight build. You can try the same and hope it helps.

Comment: The better approach, of course, is to let the Product fix this for you - so while you may be able to patch it, best is to let us fix it for you...

Comment: completely agree Idan - but this is a good solution to "get by" in the dev phases to isolate the issue and make progress until the product fix is available.